# How do I solve this nonlinear ODE given the asymptotic series solutions as follows?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, asymptotics, nonlinear-system, frobenius-method

Differential Equation:
$$-{\frac { \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}R}}f \left( R \right)  \right) 
^{2}}{2\,f \left( R \right) }}+{\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{R}^{2}}}f
 \left( R \right) +{\frac {{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}R}}f \left( R
 \right) }{R}}+2\,f \left( R \right) -2\, \left( f \left( R \right) 
 \right) ^{2}-2\,{\frac {{B}^{2}}{f \left( R \right) {R}^{2}}}=0. $$

Series Solution at $R \to 0$:
$${R}^{-2}+1+ \left( {\frac {{B}^{2}}{3}}+{\frac{1}{3}} \right) {R}^{2}
+ \left( {\frac{2}{33}}+{\frac {2\,{B}^{2}}{33}} \right) {R}^{4}+
 \left( {\frac{31}{2277}}+{\frac {53\,{B}^{2}}{2277}}+{\frac {2\,{B}^{
4}}{207}} \right) {R}^{6}+ \left( {\frac{70}{29601}}+{\frac {136\,{B}^
{2}}{29601}}+{\frac {2\,{B}^{4}}{897}} \right) {R}^{8}+O \left( {R}^{
10} \right).$$

Series Solution as $R \to \infty$:
$$1-{\frac {{B}^{2}}{{R}^{2}}}+{\frac {-2\,{B}^{4}-2\,{B}^{2}}{{R}^{4}}}
+{\frac {-7\,{B}^{6}-23\,{B}^{4}-16\,{B}^{2}}{{R}^{6}}}+{\frac {-30\,{
B}^{8}-216\,{B}^{6}-474\,{B}^{4}-288\,{B}^{2}}{{R}^{8}}}+O \left( {R}^
{-10} \right) .$$

B is a free parameter. I tried solving it like a boundary value problem using series solution at very small R and large R as boundary conditions. I tried Newton iteration and imaginary time propagation for that. But that worked only for B=1.

If I try solving it as an initial value problem starting from some Rmax, even RKF45 doesn't give good result.

Can someone please suggest either analytical or numerical way of solving this equation? Or perhaps a way of analyzing the properties of this differential equation other than frobenius series solution?

(If the questions lacks details, please let me know before downvoting)

Edit: 2 downvotes without any explanation. I mean if you don’t wanna respond, then don’t respond. Why do you have to ruin my chances of getting any help? This is the worst forum. Most of the times people just keep downvoting without any explanation.

Comment: Taking $f(R)=u(R)^2$ yields a bit neater equation: \begin{align} u^3u’’+uu’-u^6+u^4=\frac{B^2}{R^2} \end{align}

Comment: @EliBartlett I tried that way as well. But it didn’t help. And another problem is, asymptotic series solutions of u(R) can be positive or negative whereas here they’re strictly positive for f(R). Thanks for the comment anyway

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/709447/2451

Comment: How are the asymptotical expansions obtained? I have a *feeling* that the problem might have a solution only for a set of values for $B$, like in eigenproblems

Comment: @uranix thanks very much for the response. I just found the frobenius series solution. I did it such that f(R) is 1 as R—>infinity and it’s singular at R=0. Could you please suggest a way of finding the set of values of B for which the solution exists?

Comment: Ok, the problem is the Frobenius methid. It gives you a single solution, while there is a single-parametric family of solitions that are unbounded at $R = 0$. Similarly at $R = \infty$ there should be a single-parametric family. Intersection of the two families gives the solution of the problem. But it is inpractical, I'm working on an alternative suggestion

Comment: @uranix Actually I do get 2-3 series solutions at infinity and 2-3 solutions at 0 if I remember correctly. But since this is a nonlinear system, linear combination may not be a solution. Therefore, finding arbitrary constants of linear combinations by matching combinations of asymptotic series from both ends, isn’t an option unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd prefer do a simple transformation $f(R) = (u(R))^2$ suggested by @EliBartlett.

After some manipulation with computer algebra system I got
$$
R\frac{d}{dR}\left(R \frac{du}{dR}\right) = R^2 (u^3 - u) + \frac{B^2}{u^3}
$$

Frobenius analysis shows that $u \sim \frac{1}{R}$ near $R = 0$. Let's introduce $x = \log R$ and $w = \log u$. The domain for $x$ becomes $(-\infty, -\infty)$ and the boundary conditions $w \to -x$ when $x \to -\infty$ and $w(+\infty) = 0$. Also $R \frac{d}{dR} = \frac{d}{dx}$.

The equation becomes
$$
\frac{d^2}{dx^2} e^w = e^{2x} (e^{3w} - e^w) + B^2 e^{-3w}.
$$

Consider a finite interval $x \in [-L, L]$ and a regular grid with step $h = \frac{2L}{N}$. The discrete problem becomes
$$
\frac{e^{w_{n+1}} - 2e^{w_n} + e^{w_{n-1}}}{h^2} = 
e^{2x_n} (e^{3w_n} - e^{w_n}) + B^2 e^{-3w_n}, \quad n = 1, \dots, N-1.\\
w_0 = -x_0, \quad w_N = 0.
$$
To avoid numerical cancellation let's divide the $n$-th equation by $e^{w_n}$:
$$
\frac{e^{w_{n+1} - w_n} - 2 + e^{w_{n-1} - w_n}}{h^2} = 
e^{2x_n} (e^{2w_n} - 1) + B^2 e^{-4w_n}, \quad n = 1, \dots, N-1.\\
w_0 = -x_0, \quad w_N = 0.
$$
This is a system that can be plugged into the Newton solver.

I've implemented this in Python (can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/uranix/c617b7694e5dfa22bf7e9107c8b1e19d)). Unfortunately, it works only when $B \lesssim 1.117$. I tried to make Newton's method robust by introducing safety factors, but no luck. I also tried scipy nonlinear solvers and they also hit a wall of no-convergence near $B = 1.117$. I feel that the problem has no solution for such $B$.

Comment: Thanks very much for a detailed comment. I really appreciate it. Actually I tried this first and couldn’t get anything sensible for B>=1.118 using both Newton iteration and imaginary time propagation. Then I thought maybe u(R) can be positive or negative. That’s why I thought of using asymptotic series solutions of f(R) instead. That’s why I posted the ODE and asymptotic series for f(R). Again, thanks very much for the detailed comment. I also tried solving this as an IVP of two coupled first order ODEs from right boundary but the system seems stiff and even RKF45 gives nonsensical results.

Comment: @SachinVaidya Have you tried homotopy continuation method? That is trying to advance the solution for $B$ into a solution for $B + \Delta B$?

Comment: I haven’t tried that yet. I’ll check it out and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Hey, sorry I aven’t managed to try this out yet. Have been stuck in and stressed because of visa renewal process. Btw, any comments on the IVP with RKF45 I mentioned above ?  Or some alternative to that ?

Comment: @SachinVaidya by IVP you mean shooting method? I don't find it robust enough for this problem. Small perturbations of the initial slope and the solution may easily overshoot.

Comment: that’s what I also thought. But my professor kept insisting on trying that. But as I said earlier, the system seems very stiff when handled that way

Comment: $$ {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{r}^{2}}}\rho \left( r \right) +{\frac {{
\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}r}}\rho \left( r \right) }{r}}+\rho \left( r
 \right) - \left( \rho \left( r \right)  \right) ^{3}-{\frac {p+
 \left( 1-p \right) {B}^{2}}{{r}^{2} \left( \rho \left( r \right) 
 \right) ^{3}}} $$

I tried homotopy continuation with this. Not sure if the implementation is correct. Started with the solution for B=1 as initial condition when p=1. Actual B I tried solving for was B=1.5. Then tuned p from 1 to 0 with steps of 0.001. But Newton iteration starts giving nonsensical result after p~0.8

Comment: $B_{eff} = \sqrt{0.8 + 0.2 \cdot 1.5^2} = 1.118$ is again the problem

Comment: right. Do you have any other way of implementing this in mind?

Comment: yes. I just wrote the equation for rho instead of rho^2

Comment: Hi!! Any suggestions?

Comment: @SachinVaidya sorry, out of ideas. The only thing I can say that there's no smooth transition between solutions for $B < 1.18$ and $B > 1.18$ (if they exist). Maybe try to construct some approximated soluton in $B \to \infty$ limit and try to go backwards by $B$.

Comment: Oh okay. No problem. Thanks very much for looking into the problem in great detail. I appreciate it.